# Preventing conflicts when deploying multiple distros to PyPI using Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci, pypi

I'd like Travis CI to build and deploy the following artefacts to PyPI whenever a new commit hits the `master` branch:

- Python 2 wheel
- Python 3 wheel
- Source

To make this happen, I've added the following to [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/blob/85bbc7da14f3ff99e7e0b0fd482e8cbea063a7fd/.travis.yml):

```
language: python
python:
  - '2.7'
  - '3.5'
  - '3.6'
deploy:
  on:
    branch: master
  provider: pypi
  distribution: bdist_wheel sdist
```

For normal build/test, the configuration works great.  However, it introduces a race condition [when deploying to PyPI](https://travis-ci.org/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/jobs/279121774):

```
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading PyOTA-2.0.0b1.tar.gz
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: File already exists. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

What changes should I make to `.travis.yml` to get Travis CI to deploy the correct artefacts to PyPI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem today and eventually found this under-documented gem:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  skip_existing: true
  ...
```

I use `skip_existing: true` on a project to get source and wheels published once even though I test across a couple of different configurations and python versions. Handy. More details in this [resolved github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7851). I also submitted a [documentation diff](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/compare/master...bcavagnolo:patch-1).

Answer (score 5):

Some days I think outside the box; other days it's just a really big box.

Previously, this project needed separate wheels for Python 2 and Python 3, so I needed Travis CI to build wheels using different versions of Python.

But recently I got the project to build universal wheels correctly, so now Travis can build all of the deployment artefacts using any one version of Python.

I modified `.travis.yml` accordingly, and [everything is working great](https://travis-ci.org/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/builds/279129400):

```
deploy:
  on:
    branch: master
    python: '3.6'
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  It is not what I was expecting, but based on my research, this is the correct answer.  I was looking for a way to separate the build and testing from the deployment, and this achieves that, but not in the way I was expecting.  Thanks for helping out!  Like you, I was already building universal wheels, but is it worth updating your response to include how you did that in setup.py with `options={'bdist_wheel': {'universal': True}}`?

Comment: Ah, interesting; I didn't know that was an option.  I put that in `setup.cfg`.